# Creating a generator over a zarr array with start and end for pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, zarr

I'm working on a pytorch project where my data is saved in `zarr`.

Random access on `zarr` is costly, but thanks to `zarr` using a blockwise cache, iteration is really quick. To harness this fact, I use an `IterableDataset` together with multiple workers:

```py
class Data(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, path, start=None, end=None):
        super(Data, self).__init__()
        store = zarr.DirectoryStore(path)
        self.array = zarr.open(store, mode='r')

        if start is None:
            start = 0
        if end is None:
            end = self.array.shape[0]

        assert end > start

        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return islice(self.array, self.start, self.end)
```

The issue is that `self.array` has on the order of `10e9` rows and for consecutive workers, as `self.start` and `self.end` naturally get bigger, creating the generators like `itertools.islice(array, start, end)` takes a significant time out of my training/validation processes, because `islice` still has to iterate over the unneeded elements until it gets to `start`. Once a generator is created per each worker, this works like a charm, but to get there takes too long.

Is there a better way to create such a generator? Or maybe there's a smarter way to use `zarr` in `pytorch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: As of March 2021 this change has been merged into zarr.

I took a small dive into zarr and it looks like this will most easily be enabled from inside zarr. I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-python/issues/615), in the meantime I made a [fork of zarr](https://github.com/yetyetanotherusername/zarr-python/tree/start-stop-for-iterator) that implements the function `array.islice(start, end)`.

The dataset `__iter__` method then looks like this:

```py
def __iter__(self):
    return self.array.islice(self.start, self.end)
```